# Connect to Google Account without setting SRV Records

Tags: xmpp, strophe, google-talk, punjab

Is there any way I can bypass the setting SRV records.
How can you connect to mycompany.com which is a google account, without having to set the SRV records.

I am using the combination of Strophe + Punjab to connect to Google XMPP service for building chat application.
I am able to connect using a gmail account (my_mail@gmail.com) successfully.
I want to connect using my_mail@mycompany.com which is a google account.
I have come across posts with solution which require SRV records to be set which are used to turn the domain part of the jid into a hostname/port to connect.

Regards, Nitish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved..

Seems the issue is while authenticating using the password, it throws `remote-connection-failed` exception.

Using the token retrieved from OAuth2 mechanism to authenticate the Google Talk Server solves the problem.